# NFSv4 - ACLs not working

Tags: ubuntu, debian, nfs, access-control-list, nfs4

I've setup an NFSv4 server (Debian) and client (Ubuntu/Mythbuntu). It seems that uid *username* mapping is working nicely out-of-the-box (I get correct usernames on ls -l if the usernames match between the two boxes, even if the uids don't), but ACLs are not working. I've installed nfs4-acl-tools and I can read the ACLs correctly on the client, but they don't get applied.

What needs to be done for ACLs to work?

To clarify; username mapping works for regular permissions. ACLs are applied using uid/gid (I can even set ACLs by uid and they work).

Comment: Does the server mount this filesystem with the 'acl' option?

Comment: doh! the filesystem's fstab entry has the acl option, but it's not applying. Different issue

Comment: it is mounted as acl, but somehow mount doesn't show the acl flag. The ACLs are enforced on the server filesystem, but not when they are accessed via NFS.

Answer (score 1):

you need nfs4 acls, not posix acls. As far as I know, no linux nfs server provides that yet.

The easies way to get it is to get a zfs enabled system, like nexentastor. If you have a Netapp filer that one works great too.

Comment: Huh, ACLs are working over NFS, it's just that UID/GID mapping works only for regular permission bits- ACLs work when UID/GIDs match...

Comment: yes, but you mentioned the nfs4-acl-tools and those do not work with the posix acls.